# Which Android widget should I use for a static text label?

Tags: android, textview

I just want a simple non-editable text label but there doesn't seem to be a widget explicitly for it.  The closest thing seems to be a [android.widget.TextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html).  But the documentation says a "TextView is a complete text editor".  That seems like overkill for a simple label.  I don't want to bloat my application.  Is there a more appropriate widget?

Or am I approaching this the wrong way?  For example, let's say I'm building a settings screen, is there a layout I should choose which gives me labels for the properties so I don't have to specify widgets for the labels?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there a more appropriate widget?

No.

> I don't want to bloat my application.

You won't, unless you put a ton of text in it. While `TextView` has a lot of code, your process will already have access to that code, whether you use `TextView` or not. The only "bloat" would come from the actual heap space used by the `TextView` object itself (and objects that it holds).

> For example, let's say I'm building a settings screen, is there a layout I should choose which gives me labels for the properties so I don't have to specify widgets for the labels?

Typically, we would use a `PreferenceFragment`, backed by a preference XML resource, instead of having any layout or widgets.

But, if you wanted to roll your own for some reason, use `TextView` for the labels.

Comment: This is stunning.